# how to swap the third column with the last column, and then delete the swapped last column in R

Tags: r

i want to swap a specific column with the last column, and then delete the last column after swapping. After delete ncol(testFrame) will decrease by 1

Comment: Can you please provide sample data? Additionally, do you want to swap columns by name or position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually a reproducible example is expected but your description is clear enough to understand what you want to do.

Using `mtcars` as sample data

```
df <- mtcars
head(df)
#                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1


swap_column <- 3
cols <- seq_len(ncol(df))
df1 <- df[replace(cols, cols == swap_column, ncol(df))][-ncol(df)]

head(df1)
#                   mpg cyl carb  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6    4 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6    4 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4
#Datsun 710        22.8   4    1  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6    1 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8    2 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3
#Valiant           18.1   6    1 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3
```

We `replace` the column number `swap_column` with last column number (`ncol(df)`) and then remove the last column (`-ncol(df)`).

Answer (score 1):

We can do this conveniently with `add_column` from `tibble`.  The `.after` and `.before` parameters can take either column index or column name.  Suppose, we need to shift last column to third position

```
library(tibble)
data(mtcars)
df1 <- add_column(mtcars[-ncol(mtcars)], mtcars[ncol(mtcars)], .after = 2) 
head(df1)
#                   mpg cyl carb disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6    4  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6    4  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4
#Datsun 710        22.8   4    1  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6    1  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8    2  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3
#Valiant           18.1   6    1  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3
```